# jboss 6 remote jms bridge configuration not working

Tags: java, jboss, queue, jms, hornetq

I have to push messages from one jobss server and consume from another jboss server. For that I used jms bridge.

Added jms bridge configuration under </hornetq-server> tag in
**standalone-full.xml** and also referred dependencies via module.

```html
<jms-bridge name="simpleBridge" module="org.jboss.messaging">
     <source>
     <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory"/>
     <destination name="java:/simpleSOurceQ"/>
     </source>
     <target>
     <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
     <destination name="/queue/simpleTargetQ"/>
     <context>
     <property key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"/>
     <property key="java.naming.provider.url"    value="remote://TARGET_URL:5445"/>
     </context>
     </target>
     <quality-of-service>DUPLICATES_OK</quality-of-service>
     <failure-retry-interval>500</failure-retry-interval>
     <max-retries>1</max-retries>
     <max-batch-size>500</max-batch-size>
     <max-batch-time>500</max-batch-time>
     <add-messageID-in-header>true</add-messageID-in-header>
     </jms-bridge>
```

Deployment time, getting below ERROR in jboss,

**ERROR LOG :**
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "messaging"),
    ("jms-bridge" => "simpleBridge")
]) - **failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.messaging.jms-bridge.simpleBridge is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.simpleSourceQ]**"]}

How to resolve this?

or Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: If both source destination (java:/simpleSOurceQ) and target destination (/queue/simpleTargetQ) are defined?

Comment: As per the logs that you have posted, I believe that the source destination is not defined.

Comment: Its already defined in standalone-full.xml inside jms-destinations tag,   <jms-queue name="simpleSourceQ">
                        <entry name="jms/queue/simpleSourceQ"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/simpleSourceQ"/>
                        <durable>true</durable>
                    </jms-queue> </jms-destinations>

Comment: @VarunJain, simpleSourceQ defined in Source System and simpleTargetQ defined in Target system. Its defined in standalone-full.xml under "jms-desinations" tag

Comment: Change the <destination name="java:/simpleSOurceQ"/> to <destination name="simpleSOurceQ"/>

Comment: You should include the definition of the `jms-queue` in the original question as it is an important piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

The bridge's source is defined as:

```
<source>
   <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory"/>
   <destination name="java:/simpleSOurceQ"/>
</source>
```

However, according to a comment your `jms-queue` is defined as:

```
<jms-queue name="simpleSourceQ">
   <entry name="jms/queue/simpleSourceQ"/>
   <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/simpleSourceQ"/>
   <durable>true</durable>
</jms-queue>
```

As you can see, the `destination` name from the `source` doesn't match any of the `entry` elements from the `jms-queue` therefore the bridge dependencies are not met.  The bridge's source should reference a valid JNDI entry of the `jms-queue`.